# Exception is not not thrown

Tags: java, android, exception

I try to develop under Android. Now I try to use network.

I have the "manager class"

```
private String makeQuery(String string){
    Log.d("makeQuery", "in");
    try{
        NetTask a = new NetTask(server_url);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("makeQuery", "exception");
    }
    Log.d("makeQuery", "out");
    return "string";
}
```

It have the method for queries to my own API server over HTTP. It uses NetTask object, NetTask inheritance AsyncTask

```
public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

HttpURLConnection connection;

public NetTask(URL server) throws IOException{
    Log.d("NetTask", "Create");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    Log.d("NetTask", "Connect");
    connection.connect();
    Log.d("NetTask", "Response");
    int response = connection.getResponseCode();
    Log.d("NetTask", "The response is: " + response);
}
```

In my case I get next logs:

[makeQuery]

- in

[NetTask]

- Create
- Connect

So, why line Log.d("makeQuery", "out"); is not reachable?

Comment: Use finally after catch. The exception should be logged though.

Comment: maybe it throws another exception?

Comment: Yes, you right. It throws something else, I use Exception instead of IOException and it works. Thanks.

Comment: For network operations, I'd recommend using [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice).

Comment: it might be not throwing `IOException e` exception so check with exception  you get in logcat

Answer (score 1):

Why `Log.d("makeQuery", "out");` is un reachable?

```
 try{
        NetTask a = new NetTask(server_url);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("makeQuery", "exception");
    }
```

The reason is that `NetTask` class throws other kind of exception.

you will change to

```
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("makeQuery", "exception");
    }
```

but the good practice says catch the correct Exception, comment the exception handling and look into your LogCat for the type of Exception.